# date from toUTCString()

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I'm creating random time in random date in next month like this

```
var time = new Date(now.getFullYear(),
                    now.getMonth() + 1,
                    Math.floor(Math.random()*28), 
                    Math.floor(Math.random()*25), 
                    Math.floor(Math.random()*60), 
                    Math.floor(Math.random()*60), 
                    Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)
                    );
```

I want to save this Date as String and after convert it back to Date
I use

```
var time_for_save = time.toUTCString();
```

which gives me string like this:

```
Sat, 01 Oct 2011 07:42:38 GMT
```

How can I convert this date back to Date object?
Or is there better way to save/retrieve Date object via string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a date string representation, you can use [Date.parse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) function to get a 'the number of milliseconds between the date string and midnight of January 1, 1970.'; After that you can use the date constructor to get a new date object from the 'epoch milliseconds'.

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(time_for_save));
```

Comment: This does not preserver the UTC TimeZone. After conversion you get the date in your local timezone. Try converting current time to utc and back you will get this `Mon, 04 Jun 2018 19:26:06 GMT | Tue Jun 05 2018 00:56:06 GMT+0530`

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` constructor accepts a string:

```
var restoredDate = new Date(time_for_save);
```

Comment: not working from UTC date `Invalid Date { constructor: [Function: Date] }`

Comment: @EzequielAlanís What are you passing to the constructor? It needs to be a properly formatted date string.